# Recommend SSH clients that are free (preferably open source) for (at least) Windows which support infinite scrolling

Tags: windows, ssh, open-source

Problem: I'm currently using PuTTY for SSHing into our server from a Windows machine but, because its output buffer is limited, when I have a large (few hundred screens' worth) amount of data sent from the server the top part is lost. Logging doesn't really cut the mustard either because it's such a faff to find the log file and mess about with it.

Question: Is there anything out there which buffers the entire session or at least allows me to dynamically increase the buffer by a few MB (whilst in the session)?

Suggestions are very welcome. Perhaps there is a front end program which you have used that gives this functionality?

-Please be gentle, this is my first question. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Unfortunately, you have asked it in the wrong place. This site is for programming questions.

Comment: Why not just increase the buffer in Putty?

Comment: or use session logging so everything is stored in a log file

Comment: @Neil - thanks for the migration!
@ChristopheD - that's a good suggestion, but it can't be done retrospectively and it's still a limit (even at 2000 lines!). I was hoping for infinite scrolling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Granted, this is not the most robust solution, however in PuTTY you can [configure the number of lines of scrollback](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-scrollback) to be saved.  Setting this to an extremely high value, say 2147483647 (the maximum value possible), could help you out.  You would in effect have the biggest screen buffer PuTTY could give you.  Also, mid-session you can change this value by accessing the system menu and selecting "Change Settings."

Comment: I didn't know that was possible - thanks! Sometimes it's the obvious things that pass us by. Your pearl is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Just turn logging on and have it dumped to a text file.

Comment: I normally need the output mid-session and it's a nuisance to locate and mess about with the log file. I'm looking for the functionality to be incorporated within the client.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using `screen` on the remote side. It allows you to specify how much scroll buffer to save (see [here](http://www.samsarin.com/blog/2007/03/11/gnu-screen-working-with-the-scrollback-buffer/)) and a lot of other useful amenities.

Furthermore, it's client-independent: if you'll have to log in tomorrow from another computer, not only you can leave your sessions open, but also it will keep your preferences.

It's generally a life-saver.

Another nice tool is [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/); similar functionalities, more goodies, etc. Not sure it can be applied to your scenario, though.

Comment: I'm looking for more of a client based solution for this question, but I'll be sure to check out screen. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Still not a client based solution, as with the others listed, but another option is `script` which logs an entire session. See `man script` for more information (or some online copy of the man page like [here](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?script)).

You could combine this with `less` running in another SSH clietn window (or another window in a screen session). If you do something like `mkfifo /tmp/scriptpipe; script -f /tmp/scriptpipe` you can view this using something like `cat /tmp/scriptpipe | less` - the less tool will let you scroll back and forth as needed. The extra advantage of this is that you can keep the view scrolled back while typing new commands into the active session (useful for doing new work referring to commands+output from some time ago).

I recommend using screen in conjunction with this, either with both the active session and `less` in separate windows of the screen session or each in a separate screen session in separate clients - this means you can reconnect easily, losing no work/output, if you suffer a connection drop mid-session.

If you want to record the session to file as well as sending a copy through the pipe to less, do something like `cat /tmp/scriptpipe | tee /file/to/save/sessionlog/to | less`.

Answer (score 1):

I use a value of 99 999 lines for the backscroll and never had any problem. Of course, this will consume memory like hell, but with today's PC, this should not be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you think you're going to be running a large command and need all the output type it like this:

```
command > logfile.txt
```

Then you can `cat` or retrieve the file to your local machine to view.